# koa graphql multiline concatination

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql

I am defining the types in a sample Node GraphQL application which at the moment looks like

```
gql`
    schema {
        query: Query
    }

    type Query {
        books: [Book!]!
        book: Book!
    }

    type Book {
        id: ID!
        title: String!
        description: String!
        rating: Float!
    }
`;
```

I want to define the `types` in this case `Query` and `Book` in external files and then include then at their locations.

The requirement is that at the end it should be a multi line string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use buildSchema from graphql

bookSchema.ts

```
 const bookSchema = `
  type Book {
        id: ID!
        title: String!
        description: String!
        rating: Float!
    }`
export default bookSchema ;
```

server.js/index.jsfile  file

```
import { buildSchema } form 'graphql'
import bookSchema from 'pathofbookSchemaFile/bookSchema';
const schema =  buildSchema(`
  ${bookSchema}
  type RootQuery {
    books: [Book!]!
    book: Book!
  }
  type RootMutation { }
  schema {
    query: RootQuery
    mutation: RootMutation
  }`
);
export { schema };
```

Now you can use this schema object to pass in schema.